# Can't join the resullts

Tags: mysql

I want to find out all the employees who have the same number of children as the employees of department 111 and who were born between the years 1968 and 1969. So if in the department I have employees who have 1 and 2 children, the result of the query should be all the employees born on that date and who have 1 and 2 children

With this query i find out employees born in those years

```
select * 
from temple 
where fecna between '1968-01-01' and '1969-12-31';
```

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj8xL.png)

And here I find out all types of number of children in department 111

```
select distinct numhi 
from temple 
where numde = 111;
```

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPxIf.png)

The result should be something like this

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bTBG.png)

I tried to join both select but returns wrong data

Comment: show how you tried to join?

Comment: I tried `select * from temple where fecna between '1968-01-01' and '1969-12-31' JOIN select * from temple where numselect * from
 temple where fecna between '1968-01-01' and '1969-12-31'de = 111;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the second query in a join condition like:

```
select t1.*, 
from temple t1 
inner join (
             select distinct numhi 
             from temple 
             where numde = 111
           ) as t2 on t1.numhi=t2.numhi
where t1.fecna between '1968-01-01' and '1969-12-31';
```

Please read [MySQL JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) and [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html)

Comment: It works perfectly but what is t2 and t1?

Comment: @Black171 t2 and t1 are just [aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) , in other words you can name it as you want for clearance, make the query more readable . Take a look here for detailed explanation https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

Comment: I know aliases but didn't know that i could use them without as (refering to the first alias "t1." where is the "as"?)

Comment: @Black171  The SQL standard lets you use aliases with or without AS.  There is no difference. It's on your choice